# strftime adds unwanted characters to what I'm trying to display

Tags: c++, strftime

Hey guys I'm wondering if someone can point this out to me. I'm currently trying to display the date & time in the right hand corner of the cmd prompt but I'm getting additional characters then what I'm asking for. This is what I have so far

```
time_t rawtime;
struct tm * timeinfo;
char buffer[80];

time(&rawtime);
timeinfo = localtime(&rawtime);

// this displays "23                    Date:etcetcetc"
cout << "\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n";
cout << strftime(buffer, 80, "\t\t\t\t\t\t\tDate: %d/%m/%Y", timeinfo);
puts(buffer);
// and this displays "16Time:etcetcetc"
cout << "\t\t\t\t\t\t\t";
cout << strftime(buffer, 80,"Time: %I:%M:%S \n", timeinfo);;
puts(buffer);
```

if you can see the comments it gives me what I want but adds 23 to the first line and 16 to the other, what am I doing wrong?

Kind Regards!

JB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replace this:

```
cout << strftime(buffer, 80, "\t\t\t\t\t\t\tDate: %d/%m/%Y", timeinfo);
```

with this:

```
strftime(buffer, 80, "\t\t\t\t\t\t\tDate: %d/%m/%Y", timeinfo);
```

Comment: Thanks guys worked a treat can't believe it was something so simple!

Answer (score 1):

```
cout << strftime(buffer, 80, "\t\t\t\t\t\t\tDate: %d/%m/%Y", timeinfo);
```

and

```
cout << strftime(buffer, 80,"Time: %I:%M:%S \n", timeinfo);
```

You're sending the results of the function `strftime` to stdout (which is the number of bytes it printed to the buffer).

And `puts(buffer);` actually outputs your buffer.